# How to install git-hg in lubuntu?

Tags: apt, software-installation, git

tried: `sudo apt-get install git-hg` doesn't work.

Comment: It's not correct to say Lubuntu doesn't have it and Ubuntu does. Both of them can provide `/usr/bin/git-hg`; the problem here is you are not installing the correct package.

Comment: edited to reflect answer.

Answer (score 2):

The command is

```
sudo apt-get install hg-fast-export
```